# Eclipse RCP application custom toolbar

Tags: java, user-interface, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I am creating a custom toolbar for my RCP application.

[image]

1. As shown in figure I want to have a drop down box with three other text boxes. These are basically the input box and are interdependent. Right now each of these boxes are in separate classes. I want to bring them together in one class so it is easier to create listeners for each other.

   ```
   protected void fillCoolBar(ICoolBarManager coolBar) {

   IToolBarManager toolbar = new ToolBarManager(coolBar.getStyle());
   coolBar.add(toolbar);      

   Toolbar extraToolBar = new Toolbar("Toolbar");
   toolbar.add(extraToolBar);
   toolbar.add(new Separator());

   toolbar.add(new MyCombo("Demo Combo box"));
   toolbar.add(new Separator());

   toolbar.add(new IPaddress("Ip"));
   toolbar.add(new Separator());

   toolbar.add(new Mask("Mask"));
   toolbar.add(new Separator());

   toolbar.add(new Count("Count"));

   }

   public class IPaddress extends ControlContribution {

    Text textBox;


    public IPaddress(String id) {
        super(id);
       // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    protected Control createControl(Composite parent) {
   textBox = new Text(parent, SWT.MULTI | SWT.BORDER | SWT.WRAP);
   textBox.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL_BOTH));
   textBox.addModifyListener(new ModifyListener(){
       public void modifyText(ModifyEvent event) {
           Text text = (Text) event.widget;
           System.out.println(text.getText());
       } 
   });
   return textBox;
   }

   }
   ```
2. Thus I want to create a new custom Toolbar will all the functionalities that I want and then stick it to the original. But somehow it only shows an empty bar on the left.

   ```
   protected Control createControl(Composite parent) {
   toolBar = new ToolBar(parent, SWT.FLAT |SWT.BORDER);

   Device dev = toolBar.getDisplay();

   try {
       newi = new Image(dev, "C:\\Users\\RahmanAs\\ChipcoachWorkspace\\ChipCoach\\icons\\FileClose.png");
       opei = new Image(dev, "C:\\Users\\RahmanAs\\ChipcoachWorkspace\\ChipCoach\\icons\\FileOpen.png");


   } catch (Exception e) {
       System.out.println("Cannot load images");
       System.out.println(e.getMessage());
       System.exit(1);
   }


   ToolItem item0 = new ToolItem (toolBar, SWT.PUSH);
   item0.setImage(newi);
   item0.setText("Hello");

   ToolItem item1 = new ToolItem(toolBar, SWT.PUSH);
   item1.setText("Push");

   ToolItem item2 = new ToolItem(toolBar, SWT.PUSH);
   item2.setText("Pull");


   return toolBar;


   }
   ```
3. I also have run buttons, which I created in the plugin using Vogella's tutorial. But I cannot program their placements in this way. (For example if I want them in the beginning.) Is there a way to create them programmatically?

Answer (score 2):

I think the reason your leftmost `ToolBar` is empty is a layout issue. In my code below, I had a similar "empty" `ToolBar` problem when I did not have any buttons located outside the *custom* `ToolBar` but still in the *main* `ToolBar`. Adding in the "foo" and "bar" buttons fixed the layout issue, but I could not figure out the right calls to `layout()` or `pack()` to fix it. I think this may be related to [the bug here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=123205).

I took a swing at creating a similar `ToolBar` and built around the "RCP Mail Template" plugin-project that you can create from the "New Plug-in Project" wizard.

To address your first two concerns, I created 3 packages in the example RCP bundle (I called my project "com.bar.foo"):

1. **com.bar.foo.actions** - Contains classes that extend `ContributionControl` and wrap `Combo` and `Text` widgets. These have nothing to do with the data model and just worry about creating widgets.
2. **com.bar.foo.model** - Contains the data model. I just made up a simple model here with an IP, mask, gateway, and one or two helpful methods.
3. **com.bar.foo.toolBar** - These classes are plugged up to the main UI `ToolBar` via the `org.eclipse.ui.menus` extension point. They link the data model to the `ContributionControls` in the first package. The most important class here is `ToolBarContribution`, which effectively centralizes all of your listeners. This makes it easier for you to link the listeners for the widgets to the same model.

Here's the source for the `ToolBarContribution` (note that it addresses your first two concerns because it hooks up the listeners to the model *and* provides its own `ToolBar` to the UI):

```
package com.bar.foo.toolBar;

import org.eclipse.jface.action.Action;
import org.eclipse.jface.action.ToolBarManager;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionAdapter;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionListener;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Combo;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.ToolBar;
import org.eclipse.ui.menus.WorkbenchWindowControlContribution;

import com.bar.foo.actions.ComboContributionItem;
import com.bar.foo.actions.TextContributionItem;
import com.bar.foo.model.NetworkConfig;

public class ToolBarContribution extends WorkbenchWindowControlContribution {

    // Our data model.
    private NetworkConfig configuration = new NetworkConfig();

    // Each of these corresponds to a widget in the ToolBar.
    private Action scanAction;
    private ComboContributionItem sourceCombo;
    private TextContributionItem ipText;
    private TextContributionItem maskText;
    private TextContributionItem gatewayText;

    @Override
    protected Control createControl(Composite parent) {

        setupContributionItems();

        // Let's not get our hands messy with SWT... add IActions or
        // IContributionItems to a ToolBarManager and let the ToolBarManager
        // create the SWT ToolBar.
        ToolBarManager manager = new ToolBarManager();
        manager.add(scanAction);
        manager.add(sourceCombo);
        manager.add(ipText);
        manager.add(maskText);
        manager.add(gatewayText);

        ToolBar toolBar = manager.createControl(parent);

        // Highlight the ToolBar in red.
        toolBar.setBackground(parent.getDisplay().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_RED));

        return toolBar;
    }

    private void setupContributionItems() {
        scanAction = new Action("Scan Host") {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("Scanning...");
                String host = sourceCombo.getComboControl().getText();
                configuration.scanHost(host);
                System.out.println("Scanned!");
                refreshTexts();
            }
        };
        scanAction.setToolTipText("Scans the host for a configuration.");

        final SelectionListener comboListener = new SelectionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                ipText.getTextControl().setText("");
                maskText.getTextControl().setText("");
                gatewayText.getTextControl().setText("");
            }
        };
        sourceCombo = new ComboContributionItem("sourceCombo") {
            @Override
            public Control createControl(Composite parent) {
                // Let ComboContributionItem create the initial control.
                Control control = super.createControl(parent);
                // Now customize the Combo widget.
                Combo combo = getComboControl();
                combo.setItems(configuration.getAvailableHosts());
                combo.addSelectionListener(comboListener);
                // Return the default control.
                return control;
            }
        };

        ipText = new TextContributionItem("ipText", SWT.BORDER | SWT.SINGLE
                | SWT.READ_ONLY);
        maskText = new TextContributionItem("maskText");
        gatewayText = new TextContributionItem("gatewayText");
    }

    private void refreshTexts() {
        ipText.getTextControl().setText(configuration.getIP());
        maskText.getTextControl().setText(configuration.getMask());
        gatewayText.getTextControl().setText(configuration.getGateway());
    }
}
```

In addition to this `ToolBar`, I have two separate buttons in the *main UI* `ToolBar`, one before, and one after the *custom* `ToolBar`. Their sources are in the package com.bar.foo.toolBar. Here is the first command:

```
package com.bar.foo.toolBar;

import org.eclipse.core.commands.AbstractHandler;
import org.eclipse.core.commands.ExecutionEvent;
import org.eclipse.core.commands.ExecutionException;

public class FooHandler extends AbstractHandler {
    @Override
    public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {
        System.out.println("foo");
        return null;
    }
}
```

And here is the second one:

```
package com.bar.foo.toolBar;

import org.eclipse.core.commands.AbstractHandler;
import org.eclipse.core.commands.ExecutionEvent;
import org.eclipse.core.commands.ExecutionException;

public class BarHandler extends AbstractHandler {
    @Override
    public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {
        System.out.println("bar");
        return null;
    }
}
```

Since I didn't know too much about your data, I had to create my own model. The model in the package com.bar.foo.model is just one class:

```
package com.bar.foo.model;

public class NetworkConfig {

    private String ip = "";
    private String mask = "";
    private String gateway = "";

    public String[] getAvailableHosts() {
        return new String[] { "fooHost" };
    }

    public void scanHost(String host) { 
        if ("fooHost".equals(host)) {
            ip = "192.168.1.2";
            mask = "255.255.255.0";
            gateway = "192.168.1.1";    
        } else {
            ip = "";
            mask = "";
            gateway = "";
        }
    }

    public String getIP() {
        return ip;
    }
    public String getMask() {
        return mask;
    }   
    public String getGateway() {
        return gateway;
    }   
}
```

Now for the com.bar.foo.actions package that contains the `ControlContributions` that go in the custom `ToolBar`. Note that *neither of these two classes have anything to do with the model*, and they can be re-used elsewhere in your product.

The first class just wraps a `Combo` widget. The widget can be initially customized by overriding the `controlCreated(Combo)` method. I use that in the `ToolBarContribution` class to add a `SelectionListener` and set the `Combo`'s items. Here's the class:

```
package com.bar.foo.actions;

import org.eclipse.jface.action.ControlContribution;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Combo;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control;

public class ComboContributionItem extends ControlContribution {

    private Combo combo;

    public ComboContributionItem(String id) {
        super(id);
    }

    @Override
    protected Control createControl(Composite parent) {
        combo = new Combo(parent, SWT.READ_ONLY | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.H_SCROLL);
        return combo;
    }

    @Override
    public int computeWidth(Control control) {
        // The widget is now 100 pixels. You can new GC gc = new GC(control) and
        // use the gc.stringExtent(String) method to help compute a more dynamic
        // width.
        return 100;
    }

    public Combo getComboControl() {
        return combo;
    }
}
```

The other class in this package wraps a `Text` widget:

```
package com.bar.foo.actions;

import org.eclipse.jface.action.ControlContribution;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text;

public class TextContributionItem extends ControlContribution {

    private final int style;
    private Text text;

    public TextContributionItem(String id) {
        this(id, SWT.BORDER | SWT.SINGLE);
    }

    public TextContributionItem(String id, int style) {
        super(id);
        this.style = style;
    }

    @Override
    protected Control createControl(Composite parent) {
        text = new Text(parent, style);
        return text;
    }

    @Override
    public int computeWidth(Control control) {
        return 100;
    }

    public Text getTextControl() {
        return text;
    }
}
```

I didn't do this, but if you need to further customize the `Text` widget for your `ToolBar`, you can override the `createControl(Composite)` method just like I did when initializing the `ComboContributionItem`.

Now one last thing: I used extensions to customize the `ToolBar`. However, the same logic used by `ToolBarContribution` applies to your `fillCoolBar(ICoolBarManager)` method or your `createControl(Composite)` method, depending on which `ToolBar` you ultimately wish to modify.

In my case, here's what I added to the end of the plugin's `plugin.xml`:

```
<extension
      point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
   <menuContribution
         locationURI="toolbar:org.eclipse.ui.main.toolbar">
      <toolbar
            id="com.bar.foo.toolbar">
         <command
               commandId="com.bar.foo.commands.foo"
               label="Foo"
               style="push">
         </command>
         <control
               class="com.bar.foo.toolBar.ToolBarContribution">
         </control>
         <command
               commandId="com.bar.foo.commands.bar"
               label="Bar"
               style="push">
         </command>
      </toolbar>
   </menuContribution>
</extension>
<extension
      point="org.eclipse.ui.commands">
   <command
         id="com.bar.foo.commands.foo"
         name="Foo">
   </command>
   <command
         id="com.bar.foo.commands.bar"
         name="Bar">
   </command>
</extension>
<extension
      point="org.eclipse.ui.handlers">
   <handler
         class="com.bar.foo.toolBar.FooHandler"
         commandId="com.bar.foo.commands.foo">
   </handler>
   <handler
         class="com.bar.foo.toolBar.BarHandler"
         commandId="com.bar.foo.commands.bar">
   </handler>
</extension>
```

The commands are hooked up so that there's a button for `FooHandler` before the *custom* `ToolBar` and a button for `BarHandler` after the *custom* `ToolBar`. The order in which these commands are specified in the xml will be reflected in the application. Likewise, the order in which the items are added to the *custom* `ToolBar` will reflect in your product.

Another note on placement: You can make the menuContributions appear in different places by setting a placement in the locationURI's query, e.g., `toolbar:org.eclipse.ui.main.toolbar?after=additions`. "before" is another placement keyword like "after". More examples of this can be found [in this Eclipse help doc](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fworkbench_cmd_menus.htm).

Comment: Welcome to SO! If you need some clarification before answering then please leave a comment (well the next time, when you have enought "reputation") For now, why don't you just show how you would do it and add some sample code?