# How to add a text box to a submenu with JFace MenuManager?

Tags: java, swt, jface

I want to add a text field in menu manager. I need to display a textbox instead of options in my submenu. Can anyone tell me how to add a textbox in submenu.

Code:

```
IMenuManager submenu1 = new MenuManager("Enter Value"); 
submenu1.add(new Action("", SWT.BORDER) { @Override public void run() { } });
contextMenu.add(submenu1);
```

I want to display the text box in this submenu

Comment: Share the code snippets you have tried yet.

Comment: @Daenarys I have tried the above code

Comment: @juhi, do you really need to use MenuManager?  Can you use Menu directly?

Comment: @Basilevs Yes I need to use Menumanager. But anyhow I want to know other method also so  can you tell me the way to use menu directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO it is not possible to add SWT controls(like Combo,Text etc) as menu items but you can add SWT controls as toolbar items.

Check the documentation [here](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjface%2Faction%2FControlContribution.html) it says

> public abstract class ControlContribution
> extends ContributionItem
>
> An abstract contribution item implementation for adding an arbitrary SWT control to a tool bar. **Note, however, that these items cannot be contributed to menu bars.**
>
> The createControl framework method must be implemented by concrete subclasses.

Check this post [Eclipse RCP application custom toolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26097895/eclipse-rcp-application-custom-toolbar) to know how to add SWT controls as toolbar items.

Comment: Linked documentation is about higher level API

Comment: Question was about lower level API, this documentation is irrelevant, I mean,  OP is not obligated to use this class

Comment: @Basilevs Thats what I am telling there is **no api to add text box as menu items inside  main menu/submenus**. The documentation is relevant because using this you can add SWT controls like Combo,Text, etc to toolbar But not as menu items. If you know any such API then please post it as new answer

Comment: Can anyone tell me the alternate solution for my case ?

Comment: I think you can use Dialogs for this. Ask a separate question adding the details of what you need exactly and what you want to achieve(If possible with some sketches). Continuing long discussion on a single question is not recommended by Stackoverflow.

Comment: @ChandrayyaGK Thank you for the information about both technical and stackoverflow related things.

Comment: You are welcome. Remember to add the link of this post in the new question, so that some one else can access this answer to get familiar with the context.